# Angular7 i18n Message ... misses a translation

Tags: angular7, angular-i18n

I am in the project folder and execute the following statement in the console:

```
ng serve --configuration=de
```

The execution is broken with an error:

```
ERROR in xliff parse errors: Message ... misses a translation
```

[image: Error log]

The translation is available. What is the problem?

[image: Xlif file]

You can reproduce it by checking out the app from my repository [Bitbucket Repository](https://bitbucket.org/richard-martens/portrait-order-wizard) and run.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by switch to JIT-Variant described here [Merge with the jit compiler](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#merge-with-the-jit-compiler)

Comment: How to run particular translation then? with AOT compiler we have to run the server again. What should we do in here?